# ExtJS 6 - Textfield with inputType 'password' generating warning in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, passwords, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple ExtJS form in one of my applications and I noticed that Chrome was giving me a warning about it, saying that the password field is not contained in a form. Here's the exact message:

```
[DOM] Password field is not contained in a form:
```

Here's a fiddle that reproduces the problem: [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/307o)

Everything works fine, but I don't like seeing warnings in the console so if there is something I'm doing wrong I'd like to remedy that. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form tags are not generated on formpanels in classic.

BUT. You can use autoEl config to make it happen :)

```js
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'blah',
        title: 'panel',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                autoEl:'form', //<----- <form> tags will be created
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'user'
                    },
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'pass',
                        inputType: 'password'
                    }
                    ]
            }]
    });
}
});
```